# Identifying delphi components

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I want to use the same components used in the images below but I can't figure out if they are third-party components or just modified ones because I tried to modify the theme but could not get the same results. (I am on Embarcadero Delphi 11.3)

1- This Page Control (it has a custom Color)

[image]

2- This Button

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this program was made with Delphi? If you are you could use some resource extractor to extract embedded DFM file from which you can then extract the exact class names for specific controls that have been used. Not only that you will be able to extract specific Design-time settings for those controls so matching look of any standard controls will be a breeze.

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't know how to answer that for the PageControl.  Try using a tool like Spy++ or WinSight to look at the UI's elements and see what their actual class names are, that might give you a clue to whether it is a standard control or a custom control.
2. The buttons look like the standard Win32 [Command Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/ctrl-command-links) control.  The VCL's standard [`TButton`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TButton) component supports that type via its [`Style`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomButton.Style) property, which you can set to `bsCommandLink`. The 1st line of text is set by the button's [`Caption`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.Caption) property, the 2nd line of text is set by the [`CommandLinkHint`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomButton.CommandLinkHint) property, and the image is set by the [`Images`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomButton.Images) and [`ImageIndex`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomButton.ImageIndex) properties.